# Insulation in the basement ceiling - should it all come down?

Tags: insulation, basement

We have old (about 55 years) fiberglass insulation in our basement ceiling. Some of the fiberglass is exposed. Some of it is hanging lose. At the time, the insulation was installed there was no heat in the basement and it would get very cold in the winter time in the basement. Today, the basement is partially heated and the temperature rarely gets below 50. I am also thinking given the age of the insulation and the state it is in it is not providing much insulation.

I am concerned about health hazards of the exposed fiberglass so our plan is to take down part or all of the insulation. I had two contractors in and one advised only to take down the bad part. The other advised to take it all down. I am not sure what I should do. Please comment.

Comment: Is the basement used regularly? There aren't significant health hazards (that I'm aware of) from fiberglass. If it's shedding fibers regularly and you're down there often, that could be an issue, but otherwise, it's probably not a problem.

Comment: @crip659 Some of the insulation has gotten wet over the years. I am sure that is part of the problem.

Comment: @MiG A contractor suggested that sealing it off but he told me that it would be very expensive.

Comment: @FreeMan I am in the basement every day. When it comes to health issues, I want to error on the side of caution. Also, as it stands now the insulation is not providing much insulation.

Comment: The wet insulation should taken down and removed.  Replacing it is an option.  Sealing it is just the cost of a stable gun(~20$) and a roll of 6mm plastic, if go for cheap, or a few thousand for a very fancy ceiling.

Comment: @Bob I'm talking about stapling thick plastic to your ceiling, that's it. Unless you're being hilariously overcharged, that should be very cheap :)

Comment: We're also lacking a lot of information on the status of this roof. Can you perhaps add some pictures?

Comment: @MiG First, it is a basement ceiling, not the roof of a house. Taking pictures is a bit of a hassle. At this point, we are pretty close to just taking it all down.

Comment: If money and time aren't a trouble, remove it all, then consider redoing it if it chills the upper floor too much.

Comment: Based on your description it sounds like a walk in basement? All you need extra is some lighting or a flash :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided the best thing to do is take it all down. I am glad we did.